# Unknown query type 'spatial' How do I see what plugins Solr has loaded?

Tags: solr, spatial, spatial-query

I'm trying to setup the Spatial Search Plugin for Apache Solr with my install. It appears from the logging at startup that it found the JAR file, however when I try to run a query with just "{!spatial}" it complains it doesn't know that query type.

I'm assuming it hasn't actually picked up the plugin or something else is wrong. How can I confirm that Solr knows about that JAR?

As an aside, I only stuck the JAR in the solr/lib directory, so I'm not sure it there are additional things I need to do.

Comment: can't you just upgrade to Solr 3.1?